# Regência do verbo "reparar" em conjunto com "que"

Tags: regência, regência-verbal, norma-culta

Pelo que sei, *reparar* tem duas regências na Norma Culta:

> 1) reparar em (notar, observar, prestar atenção)
>   Não repara na bagunça!
>
> 2) reparar TD (consertar, indenizar)
>   Ele reparou o computador.

Porém, parece que quando a primeira regência for usada com *que*, omite-se o *em*, como mostram estes exemplos da Folha de São Paulo:

> - Rubem Alves, educador e psicanalista, repara que os professores não 
>     falam sobre seus alunos.
> - nem repara que o envelope foi trocado e anuncia "La La Land"
> - Ela repara que a consistência dos pingos é diferente

Isto é correto num registro formal? E se for, é a palavra *que* que causa este fenômeno?

Comment: Há uma discussão interessante sobre a omissão da preposição em orações subordinadas tanto nas objetivas indiretas quanto nas completivas nominais onde pessoas apontam o fenômeno inclusive em outras línguas. Não sei se esse tipo de elipse da preposição tem um nome. A discussão supracitada está em https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/omissão-de-preposições-em-oração-subordinada.3344668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais, parece-me que uma frase como

> nem repara **em** que o envelope foi trocado e anuncia "La La Land"

seria até um tanto estranha. Que o uso de reparar no sentido de *notar*, *observar* seguido de uma oração subordinada se faz quase sempre sem *em* é evidente (por exemplo, no corpus CETEMPúblico, há uma ocorrência com *em* por cada 500 sem a preposição).

Também há é quem defenda que a preposição *em* está oculta. Sobre o assunto tem Francisco Fernandes uma nota no seu *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* (45ª ed.):

> Nota: Repugna aos grámáticos admitir como *transitivo* o verbo *reparar* nesta acepção. Para eles, em frases como *repare que ele é prestigiado* — *não reparou que o seguiam*, está subentendida a preposição *em*, assim: *repare (em) que ele é prestigiado* — *não reparou (em) que o seguiam*. Penso, entretanto, que o complemento verbal é francamente direto, e *reparar* aí vale o mesmo que *ver*, *notar*, *observar*, *atentar em*.

Seguem-se vários exemplos da literatura com orações subordinadas completivas e continua a nota com:

> E, para terminar, estes dois exemplos de Vieira, onde é evidente a ausência do elemento prepositivo, claro ou oculto: "Coisa é muito digna de *reparar*, que tendo Catela há pouco anos dois infantes varões, hoje não tem nenhum." (Vieira, *Sermões*, VIII, 62.) "Mas é muito de *reparar* o tempo e a circunstância em que Cristo efetivamente socorreu aos Apóstolos." (Idem, *ibidem*, 74.)

Comment: Agradeço-lhe a resposta detalhada!

Comment: Também estranharia o *em* nessa frases. Então, "reparaste em se o vizinho já chegou a casa", ainda pior. Na tua primeira citação, *entretanto* ("Penso, entretanto, que o complemento [...]") significa 'no entanto', não? Tive que ler aquilo várias vezes para atinar com o sentimento do senhor.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, isso mesmo. Significado 3 do priberam.